# mediaelementjs play button

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I am using the mediaelementjs mp3 player for my website but the play button is not displaying.  Though it's still functional when you click the blank black space where it usually should be.  The volume button is also not visible (but functional) and the volume slider is also hanging off the edge of the player.

How do I fix this? I'm not experienced with code at all but this is the embedded code I'm using:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://www.newlifedeewhy.com/media/mediaelementjs/build/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.newlifedeewhy.com/media/mediaelementjs/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.newlifedeewhy.com/media/mediaelementjs/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <audio id="player2" src="http://www.newlifedeewhy.com/media/07122014-Michael-Rabbolini.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
    <script>$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();</script>
    </body></html>
```

Is this a jQuery issue or an issue with the mediaelementplayer.min.css?
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The controls.svg images is missing, check in /media/build/ folder.

Comment: I have checked my directory and the controls.svg images are definitely there.  What else could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Now see in console, jquery.js, mediaelementplayer js and css is not found. Can you check it and correct the path

Comment: Paths should be correct again, now, but still not showing the play button. (I was trialing some changes to see if it worked which is why you saw 'not found'. Sorry for that). It's still not displaying the play button...  I've even tried starting the whole thing again from the beginning, as well as downloading the latest source code and contents from the mediaelementjs GitHub but nothing has changed.

Comment: I think, it is a permission error to access thr files...please give a folder with 777 and check it

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I apologize for my ignorance, but what is "a folder with 777"? I can go try it now if I know what it is.

Comment: Never mind, it was a mime type issue for the .svg files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because the image for the play button is 'not found'. The path to the 'controls.svg' file could be wrong. It is currently looking for the image in http://www.newlifedeewhy.com/media/build/controls.svg

If the file is in the correct place, this could be a server configuration, is the svg mime type set?

If your server does not support svg, just link to the png instead (change `controls.svg` to `controls.png`)

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice. Nonetheless the answer is correct... Why the down vote?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have checked my directory and the controls.svg images are definitely there.  What else could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I just checked my server and it doesn't seem to support the .svg mime type. I've just added it as a custom type including the '+xml' at the end.
if my server doesn't support .svg (though I'm attempting to add it as custom) does that mean I have to change the controls.svg file extension to something different? Will that work?

Comment: what about the "pauseOtherPlayer:!0)" element? It's present in the mediaelement-and-player.min.js file but the other players on my webpage don't pause when another is played...
Do I need to add that element to the html embedded code? And/or change it to "pauseOtherPlayers: true"?